# React bootstrap navbar not appropriate linking to other pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I currently have an app with a few different pages, the routing works fine if I use the Link to component in the initial page, however from the navbar I get the message:

> Cannot GET /page1

And I also noticed that the link on the top of the browser goes to: http://localhost:3000/page1 as opposed to http://localhost:3000/#/cities (like it would if I use Link to).

My current navbar code is this:

```
export class NavigationBar extends Component {

    render(){
        return(    
            <Navbar>
             <Navbar.Header>
               <Navbar.Brand>
                 <a href="#">Navbar</a>
               </Navbar.Brand>
             </Navbar.Header>
             <Nav>
               <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/page1">Page1</NavItem>
               <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/page2">Page2</NavItem>
             </Nav>
        </Navbar>);
    }

}
```

If I just wrap the text up with Link to, it just works when we click on the text, which isn't what I want. What can I do so that the NavItem will behave like Link to but still look fine?

Thanks

Comment: i think, instead of `href` in `NavItems` use `linkTo='/page'` check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029939/how-to-make-a-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-in-a-react-js-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot that I need to wrap up each of my NavItem components with the LinkContainer from react-router-bootstrap.

That took care of everything.